# Magento slow on a VPS Server

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a a fresh Magento community 1.9.1.1, with no extensions, and no customization to the theme, on a 2 core VPS. I have created about 20 Categories / sub-category names, and only added one configurable product, with 3 simple products attached to it. I am not using any 3rd party cache system. I am utilizing the rwd theme.  It's really slow on the main landing page.  And even slower moving from one category to another!

I am wondering what would happen to it, if I add 30,000 products?  Why is it so slow?  Any recommendation on how to speed this **thing** up.  It's crazy.

---

Note to people who placed this question on hold:
I am being told to be more specific about the question, the question is too broad. The question is being placed on hold!!!
Believe me if could be more specific about what’s wrong, I would have solved the problem and fixed it myself, and not be here, or if I could afford to hire an expert, I would have done so and not be here again to seek help from experts.

It is a simple question and I don’t know how to get more specific about it?  Brand new installation of Magento, rwd theme, with ZERO products added, on a VPS server, with 2 core processor and 4 gig of ram. Regardless of how many sites are on the server, Magento should not crawl like it does.

Basic guide line topics should be:
-   What can be done on Back-end on the Magento side?  What extension could be added? What can be optimized? … 
-   What can be done on a server? Add more ram? Add more processors? Add server side caching modules? …

Regarding VPS vs dedicated servers. If you read the following comments, some people are stating that, they have hundreds of Magento sites running on VPS!  How are they doing it?

So **Fabian**, **Amit**, **liyakat**, **Keyul**  & **Marius**.  I don’t know how to get more specific?  I need help from experts like you to lead and teach how things are done.

That’s why people come to stackexchange!

Comment: anyway this question was answered 1k times - study linux and web stack optimization or hire some professional magento/linux admin....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug load time issues on local machine](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32939/debug-load-time-issues-on-local-machine)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Page Speed](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/magento-page-speed)

Comment: @ADM I am new to Magento. And have been looking and browsing this site for weeks, inside and out.  How everyone's opinion is different; as we just noticed on this thread. I am trying to find a guide, so I could optimize Magento itself fist and then move to fix the server. I would appreciate it, if you know of a thread on this or any other board. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are so many things that could affect site speed, regardless of the software you are using. Its almost impossible to tell why your site is slow without more information. What is "slow"? Is the initial document load slow, if so what speed are we talking? Or is the document OK but the frontend slow? Are you using 3rd party extensions? Have you customized the theme? What are you using for a web server? What cache system are you using?

Comment: guide? sure, yes, i know these - its here http://httpd.apache.org/ , here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/   ,  and here http://php.net/docs.php

Comment: @ADM genius answer.  Why do you even bother posting? You think you are helping or just being funny?

Comment: magento is running since 2008, google has 1k links to any sort of guides, etc...  looks like you think you are the first one who stuck??